# Problema al generar números random en una matriz en java

Tags: java

Tengo un programa donde debo pedir al usuario los valores de la matriz y que los datos de ésta se generen automáticamente.

Todo está bien hasta donde los datos se generan automáticamente.

Este es el fragmento:

```
for (m=0; m < mat1.length; m++) {
      for (n=0; n < mat1[m].length; n++) {
      mat1[m][n] = (int) (Math.random()*9+1);
```

El problema radica en que cuando corro el programa y me da el promedio, justo después de dármelo, me da el error

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
> ```

Justo en la linea

```
for (n=0; n < mat1[m].length; n++) {
```

¿Qué es lo que está mal?

---

Este es todo el código en caso de ser necesario:

```
System.out.println("Digite el tamaño M de la matriz");
      int m = lea.nextInt();
      System.out.println("Digite el tamaño N de la matriz");
      int n = lea.nextInt();
      int [][] mat1 = new int[m][n]; 
for (m=0; m < mat1.length; m++) {
      for (n=0; n < mat1[m].length; n++) {
      mat1[m][n] = (int) (Math.random()*9+1);

      double suma = 0; 
double promedio = 0; 

for (m = 0; m < mat1.length; m ++) 
{ 
for( n = 0; n < mat1[m].length; n++) 
{ 
suma = suma + mat1[m][n]; 
} 
} 
promedio = suma / ( m*n ) ; 

System.out.println("El promedio de todos los valores es..." + promedio);
  }
```

Comment: La excepción `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` la lanza la JVM cuando **se trata de acceder a un índice fuera del límite definido para un array**; es decir, sucede si por ejemplo tienes un array de 10 elementos de longitud y quieres acceder al índice 10 (onceavo elemento). Verifica que se esté accediendo siempre a un índice dentro de lo que comprende el array.

Comment: Haces muchos bucles anidados. Haz primero los bucles que rellenan la matriz y después calcula la suma y el promedio a parte. Parece que con tanto bucle se lía con alguna variable.

Answer (score 3):

ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, puede leer mas sobre esto por internet, pero basicamente es que usted esta intentado acceder a una posicion que no es correcta dentro del `array[][]`.

---

Su "error" posiblemente es dado a que esta reutilizando usando `m` - `n` dentro del un `for` que este no ha sido terminado.

```
for (m=0; m < mat1.length; m++) {                // 1a
      for (n=0; n < mat1[m].length; n++) {       // 2a
      mat1[m][n] = (int) (Math.random()*9+1);

      double suma = 0; 
      double promedio = 0; 

for (m = 0; m < mat1.length; m ++) {             // 3a
for( n = 0; n < mat1[m].length; n++) {           // 4a
    suma = suma + mat1[m][n]; 
}                                                // 4a
}                                                // 3a
promedio = suma / ( m*n ) ; 

System.out.println("El promedio de todos los valores es..." + promedio);
  }  
                                        //2a
```

*me imagino que el cierre que falta -> `}`   //1a estara por aqui y no lo puso.*

y al usar la misma variable es posible que al emplear `m++` o `n++` estas se aumenten de tal manera que el valor, al aplicarlo en alguna parte del `array[][`] para acceder a el salta el -> ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

la solucion rapida podria ser que empleara algo asi `int ? = 0`:

```
for (int a = 0; a < mat1.length; a++) {              // 1a
          for (int b = 0; b < mat1[a].length; b++) { // 2a
```

y de esta manera en el resto de los `for` notese `int a = 0` - `int b = 0`.

esto es contando que su intencion fuera anidar asi los `for`

---

algo asi pseudocode:

```
for (int a=0; a < mat1.length; a++) {
    for (int b=0; b < mat1[a].length; b++) {
        mat1[a][b] = 

        for (int g = 0; g < mat1.length; g ++) { 
            for(int j = 0; j < mat1[g].length; j++) {
                mat1[g][j] = 
            } 
        } 
    }
}
```

aunque la [indentacion](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentaci%C3%B3n) no es critica en este lenguaje, si es bueno llevar cierto orden, de ayudara a detectar errores mas facilmente y a leer mejor su codigo.

Answer (score 0):

Según entiendo con tu explicación, lo que tratas de hacer es sacar un promedio del array bidimensional. Lo que deberías hacer es sacar afuera el segundo bloques de for, para que no tengas problemas con la excepción ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Guíate de este código corregido:

```
System.out.println("Digite el tamaño M de la matriz");
int m = lea.nextInt();
System.out.println("Digite el tamaño N de la matriz");
int n = lea.nextInt();
int [][] mat1 = new int[m][n];

for (m=0; m < mat1.length; m++) {
    for (n=0; n < mat1[m].length; n++) {

        mat1[m][n] = (int) (Math.random()*9+1);

    }
}

double suma = 0; 
double promedio = 0; 

for (m = 0; m < mat1.length; m ++) 
{ 
    for( n = 0; n < mat1[m].length; n++) 
    { 
        suma = suma + mat1[m][n]; 
    } 
} 

promedio = suma / ( m*n ) ; 

System.out.println("El promedio de todos los valores es..." + promedio);
```

---

También podrías mejorar tu algoritmo, implementandolo asi:

```
System.out.println("Digite el tamaño M de la matriz");
int m = lea.nextInt();
System.out.println("Digite el tamaño N de la matriz");
int n = lea.nextInt();
int [][] mat1 = new int[m][n];

double suma = 0; 
double promedio = 0; 


for (m=0; m < mat1.length; m++) {
    for (n=0; n < mat1[m].length; n++) {

        mat1[m][n] = (int) (Math.random()*9+1);
        suma = suma + mat1[m][n];

    }
}

promedio = suma / ( m*n ) ; 

System.out.println("El promedio de todos los valores es..." + promedio);
```